# Secure against c99 and similar shells

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php5, lamp

I'm trying to secure my server as much as i can without limiting my options,
so as a first step i've prevented dangerous functions with php

```
disable_functions = "apache_child_terminate, apache_setenv, define_syslog_variables, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, eval, exec, fp, fput, ftp_connect, ftp_exec, ftp_get, ftp_login, ftp_nb_fput, ftp_put, ftp_raw, ftp_rawlist, highlight_file, ini_alter, ini_get_all, ini_restore, inject_code, mysql_pconnect, openlog, passthru, php_uname, phpAds_remoteInfo, phpAds_XmlRpc, phpAds_xmlrpcDecode, phpAds_xmlrpcEncode, popen, posix_getpwuid, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, posix_setuid, posix_uname, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_nice, proc_open, proc_terminate, shell_exec, syslog, system, xmlrpc_entity_decode"
```

but i'm still fighting directory travel, i can't seems to be able to limit it,
by using a shell script like c99 i can travel from my /home/dir to anywhere on the disc.

how can i limit it once and for all ?

Comment: Don't run insecure PHP code that allows anybody to upload a script like C99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to secure my server as much as i can without limiting my options

. . . Well that won't be very secure now, will it?
You can't secure a system by putting little bits of chewing gum over the holes you've stumbled on. You're looking at security the wrong way if you think that's the right approach.
Like [Michael Hampton said](https://serverfault.com/questions/455255/secure-against-c99-and-similar-shells#comment498017_455255), you need to start by writing *secure code*.

---

> but i'm still fighting directory travel, i can't seems to be able to limit it …
>   how can i limit it once and for all ?

`chroot` the web server. That's the only solution.
Any other steps you take are chewing gum plugging a hole - If you want to make sure malicious users can't get at anything sensitive lock them in a box that contains nothing sensitive and don't let them out.